# how to marquee images in android (automatically)?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to have the marquee functionality available in html in my android application.I don't know what do we call it in android.

for example,I have four to five images.they need be marquee either from left to right or from right to left.(automatically)

1 note-I am not asking about **Horizontal scroll view**.

What is the procedure and How can i get this feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**I GOT THE ANSWER...FOR MY QUESTION**

**ITS AUTOSLIDER**

```
 public class AutoSlider extends Activity {

    public int currentimageindex=0;
    Timer timer;
    TimerTask task;
    ImageView slidingimage;

    int[] IMAGE_IDS = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3,
            R.drawable.image4};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

        // Create runnable for posting
        final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                AnimateandSlideShow();

            }
        };

        int delay = 1000; // delay for 1 sec.

        int period = 8000; // repeat every 4 sec.

        Timer timer = new Timer();

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {

             mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);

        }

        }, delay, period);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        finish();
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
      }
       private void AnimateandSlideShow() {

        slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView_id);
        slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);

        currentimageindex++;

      }

}
```

and in your XML have just the layout and the image view with its width,height and position.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the View Pager along with the Timer:
On each time tick change the page of the view pager using pager adapter:

> Official defination of View pager:

```
Layout manager that allows the user to flip left and right through pages of data. You supply an implementation of a PagerAdapter to generate the pages that the view shows
```

Please look at some examples of View pager and view flippers :

http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/view-pager-example-in-android-development/

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/image-slideshow-using-viewflipper-in-android/ (Using view flipper)

Comment: but view pager is not being supported.....WHEREAS,VIEW FLIPPER is being supported.In the recent versions of android.

Comment: View pager is supported in the all version by using the v4 support library .Please check the official Docs:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html