# How to animate image like marquee of a TextView

Tags: android, animation

I have a problem in animating image like marquee of a TextView.
For example, if the image is translated to X-axis by 50 pixels to right, the 50 pixels in the left is will be filled by translated 50 pixels (the width of image is no changed).

Original: xxxxx50pixels, after Changed: 50pixelsxxxxx

Is there anybody can suggest me a solution?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: check this link, it may helpful for your requirement.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159171/how-to-marquee-images-in-android-automatically
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159171/how-to-marquee-images-in-android-automatically

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I want to marquee only one image itself, not multiple images like using a ViewPager.

Answer (score 0):

If you want animation with only one image then you can use .gif image for **marquee** effect.