# Make a infinite scrolling background on LinearLayout Android

Tags: android, animation, background

I would like to get a scroll effect to my background something like this http://dev.bradsknutson.com/demos/css-background-animation/

I have my LinearLayout that is matched on screen with a pattern background repeated on -x and -y but I don't know how to make scroll vertically.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159171/how-to-marquee-images-in-android-automatically

Comment: I appreciate your link but I'm still don't know how to make it because on them talk about ImageView where put different images but in my case I have only one LinearLayout, with a image background repeated and that must move up to down smothly. I don't know if I do not know if I've explained it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the XML Use a relative layout. Create a custom view. Add custom view to relative layout. add linear layout over top.

In custom view, set up a thread to handle rendering, draw background bitmap to canvas at offsets using a deltatime, make sure to tile to fill in all gaps.

here are some links to get you started.

http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2011/05/drawing-on-surfaceview.html

http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/simple-surfaceview-example-t2174100.html

[Android draw using SurfaceView and Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956583/android-draw-using-surfaceview-and-thread)